# Find all polynomials $f, g \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f(g(X))=1 + X + ... + X^{p-1}$

Tags: polynomials, integers

> Find all polynomials $f, g \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f(g(X))=1 + X
>  + ... + X^{p-1}$ where $p \gt 2$ is a prime.

---

One solution is $g = X, f =1 + X + ... + X^{p-1}$.

If $\deg(f)=m, \deg(g)=n$ then $f=\pm X^m + ... , g=\pm X^n + ... $ with $mn = p-1$

I have no idea how to get further.

**UPDATE**

$g = -X, f =1 - X + X^2 -X^3 + ... + X^{p-1}$ also $f = -X, g =- 1 - X - ... - X^{p-1}$  and $f = X, g =1 + X + ... + X^{p-1}$ are also solutions.

Comment: I think you will find out that, if we set $h (X)=1+X+X^2+\cdots+X^{p-1} $, then we can set e.g $g(X)=X-k $ and $f (X)=h (X+k) $ for any $k\in \mathbb Z $. And similar if the leading coefficient is $-1$. And similar if you swap $f $ and $g $: $g (X)=h (X)-k $, $f (X)=X+k $. This is likely to exhaust all solutions where $\deg f=1$ or $\deg g=1$. However, proving that those are all solutions... I don't have a proof yet.

Comment: @user8734617 It's a useful observation

Comment: I spent a while looking for an argument involving algebraic conjugates. But I ran into difficulties like the following when working with rational functions instead of polynomials. Consider the case $p=5$. With $g(x)=x+\dfrac1x$ and $f(x)=x^2+x-1$ we do have the relation
$$f(g(x))=\frac1{x^2}(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1).$$ In other words, something with the correct set of zeros! I then tried to do the same with two quadratic polynomials, and ran into the problem that settled the question in general as well. But, Alex Francisco got the same idea faster!

Comment: (cont'd) Anyway, I'm sure similar decompositions up to a factor that is a power of $x$ exist for other primes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(X) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m a_k X^k$ and $g(X) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n b_j X^j$. It is easy to see that $|a_m| = |b_n| = 1$.

First, consider the situation where $n = 1$. If $g(X) = X + b_0$, then$$
f(X + b_0) = 1 + X + \cdots + X^{p - 1} \Rightarrow f(X) = 1 + (X - b_0) + \cdots + (X - b_0)^m.
$$
If $g(X) = -X + b_0$, then$$
f(-X + b_0) = 1 + X + \cdots + X^{p - 1} \Rightarrow f(X) = 1 + (-X + b_0) + \cdots + (-X + b_0)^m.
$$

Next, suppose $n > 1$. Now focus on the coefficient of the $X^{p - 2} = X^{mn - 1}$ term. Expand $f(g(X))$ to get$$
\sum_{k = 0}^m a_k (g(X))^k = 1 + X + \cdots + X^{p - 1}.
$$
For $0 \leqslant k \leqslant m - 1$, $\deg(a_k (g(X))^k) = kn \leqslant (m - 1)n < mn - 1$, so the coefficient of $X^{mn - 1}$ in $f(g(X))$ is all contributed by $a_m(g(X))^m$. Note that $\deg g = n$, thus the coefficient of $X^{mn - 1}$ in $a_m(g(X))^m$ is $a_m \cdot \binom{m}{1} b_n^{m - 1} b_{n - 1} = m a_m b_{n - 1} b_n^{m - 1}$. Since the coefficient of $X^{mn - 1} = X^{p - 2}$ in $1 + X + \cdots + X^{p - 1}$ is $1$, then$$
m a_m b_{n - 1} b_n^{m - 1} = 1 \Longrightarrow m = 1.
$$
Now, if $f(X) = X + a_0$, then$$
g(X) + a_0 = 1 + X + \cdots + X^{p - 1} \Longrightarrow g(X) = 1 + X + \cdots + X^{p - 1} - a_0.
$$
If $f(X) = -X + a_0$, then$$
-g(X) + a_0 = 1 + X + \cdots + X^{p - 1} \Longrightarrow g(X) = -1 - X - \cdots - X^{p - 1} + a_0.
$$

Comment: I had the same idea (+1), but you beat me to it. Congrats!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen can you repost your answer back.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco, am I mistaken, or you never used the fact that $p $ is prime?

Comment: @user8734617 It doesn't need that condition.

Comment: That is probably why my attempts (and apparently @JyrkiLahtonen's) to look into the cyclotomic field extension were bound to be doomed.

Comment: @0x90 I honestly don't see the point. My idea was exactly the same. To look at the second highest degree term, and observe that its coefficient must be divisible by $\deg f$ when $\deg g>1$.